# Set up an old router as a wi fi extender

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to set up [this old EE bright-box router](https://shop.ee.co.uk/broadband/ee-bright-box-router) as a wifi extender for an area in the house with bad signal.

After accessing the config, it does not seem to be any way to do it, but I'm quite un-experienced. Right now the router is connected via ethernet with another router (same brand, but newer), and the wifi works in both devices really well. But I can't get the settings in the old router to act as a wifi repeater.

Comment: Save yourself the headache.. I too tried to go down this route.  A decent wifi extender can be picked up for as little as 20 USD.  I myself bought a cheap NetGear one but I don't know that they aren't ALL good.  My son was complaining about game lag on his machine on the other side of the house.. now he says that he gets very low latency (through the extender).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be possible with this router, but not with manufacturer's firmware.

You will need to do some fact finding on this unit, and make sure it is actually a Brightbox v1. There is a second iteration of that model that isn't the v2, but looks slightly different from the v1. It is unknown at this time if the second iteration has identical hardware internally, and could permanently make the unit un-bootable if it's not the v1 and flashed with third party firmware.

Read the OpenWRT wiki for this router carefully, follow the instructions to get OpenWRT running on the router. If you run into problems getting it going, keep track of the steps you have problems with. You can ask for help with it as a whole new question.

https://openwrt.org/toh/arcadyan/ar7516

After you get the OpenWRT firmware running, if you need help with setting up the configuration as a wireless repeater, ask it as a new question in the wireless-networking tag section.

Comment: I didn't cause I moved house but I'm accepting cause it looks plausible and for the effort

Comment: Is this like flashing an OS onto the router?

Comment: It is, it's putting a much better, and much more versatile OS on the box